# is there a way to make columns without pandas?

Tags: python

I currently have a list of lists and I need to put them into columns but I can't use pandas to make the columns. I currently have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
list_a = [['face1', 'face2', 'object', 'scene'], ['1', '7', '6', '5'], ['4', '3', '2', '8'], ['1', '3', '2', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

and I want it to come out in columns like this

```
face1  face2  object   scene
  1      4      1        1
  7      3      3        2
  6      2      2        3
  5      8      4        4
```

Comment: Do you have any alignment requirements?

Comment: What code have you already tried? (SO is not supposed to be a code-writing service, as I'm sure you know.)

Comment: It's just a matter of string formatting. `for x in list_a: print(*x, sep='\t')` is sufficient if you don't care much about the exact formatting.

Comment: Are you sure that column order is what you want ? It's not how Pandas makes tables. In that case before printing you should rearrange the columns.

Answer (score 1):

try using `center`:

```
list_a = [['face1', 'face2', 'object', 'scene'], ['1', '7', '6', '5'], ['4', '3', '2', '8'], ['1', '3', '2', '4'],
          ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

for item in list_a:
    for subitem in item:
        print(subitem.center(10), end='')
    print()
```

output :

```
  face1     face2     object    scene   
    1         7         6         5     
    4         3         2         8     
    1         3         2         4     
    1         2         3         4
```

Note : If your list, contains a value other than string, don't forget to convert it to string before calling `.center` on it:

```
print(str(subitem).center(10), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting to print columns.

```py
for row in list_a:
    print(''.join(f'{x:^8}' for x in row)) # 8-character wide centered columns

# output
face1   face2   object  scene  
   1       7       6       5    
   4       3       2       8    
   1       3       2       4    
   1       2       3       4
```